# How to apply patch hunk by hunk?

Tags: git, patch

Is there a way to apply patch from stash hunk by hunk like that as add hunks from working directory into stage: `git add -p`?

I am looking for similar command:

```
git stash show -p | git apply --hunk-by-hunk
```

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK there is no patch mode for apply.  However, you can apply the patch, then interactively remove the hunks (hunk-by-hunk) in the patch you don't like:

`git checkout -p`

Comment: I do not understand its reverse logic

Comment: Its a bit confusing but hit y/yes for the hunks you want to remove

Comment: With this I am OK, I am very confusing when `e`

Comment: @EugenKonkov in edit mode, you're looking at a diff between the previous commit and HEAD.  The +/- lines are the changes.  If you leave in the +/- lines then you're telling git that you want those changes of the diff  to be checked out (i.e. removed from your working tree).  If you remove the lines with +/- then you keep them in your working tree.

Comment: @EugenKonkov I do agree, it's confusing and is kind of like a double negative.